# C# external program call directory error

Tags: c#, call, external

I am working on ILOG which is developed from IBM. ILOG program can be run via cmd console as follows:

`oplrun -p C:\Users\pc_copat\opl\santez\"workName"`

When I write this code above to cmd console screen, the program is working with no error. Though, when I used these codes in c# as follows it is not working.

```
`string komut = @"oplrun -p C:\Users\pc_copat\opl\santez\ " + '\u0022' + calismaAdi + '\u0022';`

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        //startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = "/K "+komut;

        try
        {
            // Start the process with the info we specified.
            // Call WaitForExit and then the using-statement will close.
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Log error.
        }
```

I always get this error:

> 'oplrun' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is this path correct? `C:\Users\pc_copat\opl\santez\ " + '\u0022' + calismaAdi + '\u0022'`, I see multiple slashes and a few extra quotes?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing parameters, you can use StandardInput.WriteLine to execute commands on cmd...

```
    string komut = @"oplrun -p C:\Users\pc_copat\opl\santez\ " + '\u0022' + calismaAdi + '\u0022';

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    //startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    //startInfo.Arguments = "/K "+komut;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    string currentFolderString = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // Not sure if this will work but it should be your directory containing the oplrun.exe
    try
    {
        // Start the process with the info we specified.
        // Call WaitForExit and then the using-statement will close.
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            exeProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(string.format("cd \"{0}\"", currentFolderString)); // navigate to the oplrun.exe directory
            exeProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(komut); // execute komut instead of as param
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Log error.
    }
```